# Conditional logic for last property of an object

Tags: javascript

Using an object literal, I am attempting to add keys and values to a string and append a character on the end of each iteration, like so:

```
var url = 'www.example.com/'

var properties = {'foo': 'xyz123', 'bar': 456, 'baz': true}

for (prop in properties) {
  url = url + prop + '=' + properties[prop] + '&';
}
```

However, I would like to add conditional logic that does not add the `'&'` if it's the last property:

```
for (prop in properties) {
  // If not last:
    url = url + prop + '=' + properties[prop] + '&';
  // Otherwise:
    url = url + prop + '=' + properties[prop];
}
```

Considering objects are not indexed, how do I determine the last property of an object to perform this task?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the language spec does not impose any ordering on object properties. That is, no property is "first" or "last"; they're all just properties in no particular order. If you need a particular ordering, use an array.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to add `&` in front of properties that are not *first*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it the other way around - prepend an `&` instead of appending `&`

```
var url = 'www.example.com/?' //add a ? to indicate a query string is starting

var properties = {'foo': 'xyz123', 'bar': 456, 'baz': true}

for (prop in properties) {
  url = url + '&' + prop + '=' + properties[prop];
}
```

This being said - is there a real difference if you have a trailing `&`?

Answer (score 3):

More elegant way is to use temporary array for parameters and then join it's entries with `&`:

```
var url = 'www.example.com/', buf = [];

var properties = {'foo': 'xyz123', 'bar': 456, 'baz': true}

for (prop in properties) {
  buf.push(prop + '=' + properties[prop]);
}
url = url + buf.join('&');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. One would be to append the `&` to all properties and remove it from the last (keep a reference while iterating, remove from the reference after the for..in).
Another way is to get an ordered list of properties and simply iterate on that:

```
var keys = Object.keys(properties);

for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
  url = url + prop + '=' + properties[prop] + (i === keys.length-1 ? '' : '&');
}
```

**Disclaimer**: Object properties are not ordered. The above code does place `&` at the end of all properties but one and usual iterations over object properties will probably return the ones with `&` first, but that is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

One quick & dirty solution I have used is the substr method.  Just add the trailing '&' to all the values, then remove it later:

```
url = urlWithExtraAmpersand.substr(urlWithExtraAmpersand.length - 1);
```